# Does the word "discharge" sound more like /dɪstʃɑːʳdʒ/ or /dɪsdʒɑːʳdʒ/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, consonants, ipa

Does the word **discharge** sound more like /dɪ**stʃ**ɑːʳdʒ/ or /dɪ**sdʒ**ɑːʳdʒ/?

How about ***exchange*** or ***disproportion***?

Do they sound more like /ɪk**stʃ**eɪndʒ/ or /ɪk**sdʒ**eɪndʒ/?

/dɪ**sp**rəpɔːʳʃən/ or /dɪ**sb**rəpɔːʳʃən/?

I know the word ***student*** which commonly sounds like /s**dj**uːdənt/.

and the dictionary says its IPA transcription is /**st**juːdənt/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Student doesn't sound like *[ˈ**sd**juːdn̩t]
- discharge ......................... *[dɪˈ**sd͡ʒ**ɑːd͡ʒ]
- spy ................................... *[**sb**aɪ]
- describe ........................... *[dɪˈ**sg**raɪb]
- system ............................. *[ˈsɪ**sd**əm]
- school .............................. *[**sg**uːl]

you think they do because you're confusing the plosives in your native language with the plosives in English.

English has two bilabial plosives—voiced bilabial plosive /b/ and voiceless bilabial plosive /p/, two alveolar plosives—voiced /d/ and voiceless /t/ and two velar plosives—voiced /g/ and voiceless /k/

In English, they're distinguished through voicing; /p/, /t/ and /k/ are voiceless while /b/, /d/ and /g/ are their corresponding voiced counterparts.

They are phonemes—mental representation of sounds, but can be realised in more than one way. For instance, /t/ has many allophones (realisations):

- in the beginning of a stressed syllable, it's realised [tʰ] (aspirated: with a big puff of air)
- in unstressed syllables, it can be realised [t] (no big puff of air)
- in most American accents, t in the middle of vowels can be realised [ɾ] (alveolar flap as in *wa[ɾ]er*)
- some dialects of British English use a glottal stop as in *wa[ʔ]er*.

All these are the different realisations of the same phoneme /t/.

The most common allophones of /t/, /p/ and /k/ are respectively [tʰ, t], [pʰ, p] and [kʰ, k].

- [pʰ tʰ kʰ] → unvoiced and **aspirated**
- [p t k] → unvoiced and ***un*aspirated**

In English, if you use them interchangeably, they won't change the meaning of the word. For example, the word *pin* is supposed to be pronounced [pʰɪn], but if you pronounced the p without aspiration (i.e. [pɪn]), it wouldn't change the meaning (as Spanish speakers usually do). That is to say, aspiration isn't phonemic in English.

Whereas in other languages like Chinese, aspiration is a distinctive feature for certain sounds (i.e. aspiration is phonemic).

In Pinyin:

- the letter ⟨b⟩ is used to represent '**un**aspirated voiceless bilabial plosive', IPA [p]
- ⟨d⟩ for '**un**aspirated voiceless alveolar plosive', IPA [t]
- ⟨ɡ⟩ for '**un**aspirated voiceless velar plosive', IPA [k]

By contrast,

- ⟨p⟩ is used to represent 'voiceless *aspirated* bilabial plosive', IPA [pʰ]
- ⟨t⟩ for 'voiceless *aspirated* alveolar plosive', IPA [tʰ]
- ⟨k⟩ for 'voiceless *aspirated* velar plosive', IPA [kʰ]

In words beginning  ⟨sp-⟩, ⟨st-⟩, and ⟨sk-⟩, English speakers use 'voiceless *unaspirated* plosives'. For instance, the p in *pie* is aspirated, but unaspirated in *spy*:

- pie → [pʰaɪ]
- spy → [spaɪ] not *[spʰaɪ]

In Pinyin, ⟨sp-⟩, ⟨st-⟩, ⟨sk-⟩ would be represented by ⟨sb-⟩, ⟨sd-⟩, and ⟨sg-⟩, respectively. So you see there's a mismatch between English plosives and Chinese plosives.

That's why you hear *sdudent* for *student*, *sgool* for *school* and *sby* for *spy*.

Whereas in words beginning ⟨p-⟩, ⟨t-⟩ and ⟨k-⟩, English speakers use 'voiceless *aspirated* plosives'. Examples:

- pie → [pʰaɪ]
- time → [tʰaɪm]
- kite → [kʰaɪt]

In Pinyin, ⟨p-⟩, ⟨t-⟩, ⟨k-⟩ would also be represented by ⟨p-⟩, ⟨t-⟩, and ⟨k-⟩, respectively. So you hear *pie, time, kite* correctly.

The same thing is going on with affricates (/t͡ʃ/ and /d͡ʒ/). Affricates in some dialects of English are aspirated, but it varies from speaker to speaker. And if you hear [st͡ʃ] as [sd͡ʒ], then there certainly is aspiration which is affected by the preceding [s] (the same way as [s] affects the aspiration of p, t and k).

Or if /t͡ʃ/ and /d͡ʒ/ are unaspirated, then they're only distinguished through voicing in English and voicing in Chinese is not phonemic so Chinese speakers confuse them easily.

---

**Notes:**

- 'Plosives' are the consonants that are produced by stopping the airflow at a particular place of articulation, accompanied by a sudden release of air such as /p, b, t, d, g, k/ etc.
- I've marked incorrect/ill-formed sequences with a preceding asterisk (*)
- 'Bilabial plosives' are the sounds that are articulated with both the lips: /b/ and /p/
- the superscript h [ʰ] represents aspiration; a big puff of air
- I've used **/slashes/** for phonemic data, **[square brackets]** for phonetic data and **⟨angled brackets⟩** for orthography (spelling)
- I don't know how to format it properly, that's why I've used ' ............. ' instead of ditto marks.

Comment: I think the use of the glottal t in water would be thought of as a dialect usage in the UK and the standard would be [t]

Comment: @mdewey: Yeah it's dialectal

Comment: I think the explanation in your answer can apply to ZhuYin (BoPoMoFo) too.

Comment: Cast my eye over th wiki article on bopomofo and I think it applies to that

Comment: The P in pie and the P in spy are *not* pronounced differently.  At least not in the AmE I grew up speaking

Comment: @Kevin: They **are** different at the phonetic level as I explained. Also, does it really deserve a downvote? (Note that I haven't downvoted your answer to the other question.)

Comment: @void I downvoted it because I think it's wrong, not out of retribution.  I must have said the words pie and spy a few hundred times in the last day or so I can hear absolutely no difference between the pronunciation of the P's.  Maybe it's a regional thing or maybe I have something like tone-deafness (yes, I know it's not actually a tonal difference) and can't hear it, but to me, Spy sounds like pie with an s in front of it. I even feel the puff of aspirated air for both

Comment: @Kevin: There *is* a puff of air in *spy* but almost negligible as compared to *pie*. *Sp-* sequences are less strongly aspirated than word-initial or syllable-initial p's in English. There's a striking difference between the p of *pie* and that of *spy*. But because English doesn't contrast **p** and **pʰ**, native speakers of English think of them as the same sound **/p/**. I don't see how my answer is wrong. If you have a better answer, go ahead and post it. You may be a native English speaker, but I'm afraid you're not a phonetician and don't know how to analyse speech sounds.

Comment: @void Fair enough. Unfortunately, the site won't let me change my vote

Comment: @Kevin: I don't mind the downvote at least you left a comment acknowledging it's yours (unlike the drive by downvoters).